# Getting row data from SlickGrid when using the pager plugin

Tags: slickgrid

I'm using SlickGrid with the pager plugin. My intent is to display line items in SlickGrid and allow the user to double click on a row to get more detail. I have code that seems to work fine but it feels as though I'm doing this the hard way:

```
grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var selectedIndex = parseInt(grid.getSelectedRows());
    var pageInfo = dataView.getPagingInfo();
    var pageSize = pageInfo.pageSize;
    var pageNum = pageInfo.pageNum;
    var idx = pageSize*pageNum + selectedIndex;
    var asset = rows[idx].assetName;
    alert("Selected Asset is " + asset);
});
```

I've seen other questions posted where people did a `grid.getData()[selectedIndex]` or a `dataView.getItemById(selectedIndex)`, but since `selectedIndex` is always a 0 to something number, I always got data from the first page in my list regardless of which page I was on. Is there a direct way to map a selected index on a page to the actual row in the data array? Again, the code above seems to work fine - just feels like I'm missing an obvious method somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function(e, args) {
  alert("Selected asset is " + args.item);
  alert("Or " + grid.getData().getItem(args.row));
  alert("Or " + grid.getDataItem(args.row));
});
```